# What is the best practice for implementing a download in Android 2.1?

Tags: android, download

I'm really a newbie to android world.
And now i'm coding for downloading a file from my dropbox storage.
I want to know what will be the best practice for implementing a download (direct download)

I found DownloadManager, service, AsyncTask ....
DownloadManager - doesn't support on older devices, Android2.1

[Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog/3028660#3028660)

What should i use if I want to implement for android 2.1 devices ? could u guide me which method should i use and which is better way to use (less consuming resources) ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article about this. One can use AsyncTask and a service to handle the download and send broadcasts to different activities. There is also the possibility to use progress bar.
You can see the tutorial and source code at [this page](http://ootooban.com/en/2012/custom-download-manager-for-android-2-1/).